# Rails recurive view strange behaviour with object association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.1

I have a table of comments that is associated with itself for replies. Basically, a comment that has a parent_id is also a reply to his parent comment.

To render this, I use a recursive view, very simple that worked in the past, but is not working with rails 3.2.0 and ruby 2.1.1

Here is simplified code:

```
<% x = comment.replies %>
<%= comment.id %>; <%= comment.class %><br/>
<%= comment.replies.class %><br><br>
<hr>
<br><br>
<% if x and x.is_a?(Array) %>
  <%= render :partial => "/_redesign/entry/comment", :collection => x, :as => :comment%>
<% end %>
```

Output is:

> 349223; Comment
>   Array
>   349229; Comment
>   Comment

At second iteration, `comment.replies` is a Comment, not an Array, and all falls down from there.

But, if I change the first line and add a reload:

```
<% x = comment.reload.replies %>
```

all starts working, output is:

> 349223; Comment
>   Array
>   349229; Comment
>   Array
>   349230; Comment
>   Array

I would love to understand what is going on here and how can the association to return a single object instance instead of a list of them and why is working with reload.

Added the model code:

```
class Comment < Response
  acts_as_deactivatable :dependencies => [:community_news_feed_items]

  has_many :replies, :class_name=>"Comment", :foreign_key=>"referring_c_id", :order=>"date ASC"

  belongs_to :parent_comment, :class_name=>"Comment", :foreign_key=>"referring_c_id"
end
```

Comment: Can you push example app on github?

Comment: can you show us how you get replies? is it a named_scope or an association? also what rails/ruby did it work on before?

Comment: Could you please show not-simplified view? Code as it is works correctly on my machine.

Comment: I can't push the app to git, it is huge app, this is just a small part of it. It worked with rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7. I just landed on this app and I have to upgrade it to rails 3.2 and ruby 2.1.1. I fixed lots of problems, but this one beats me. I will add also the model code where the association is defined

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that when you enter the scope of the comment reply you've added an [`ActiveRecord::Association::CollectionProxy`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy) as a middleman between the original comment and the comment response. It says,

> The `@reflection` object represents a `:has_many` macro.

Which would follow from your use of `:has_many` in the model code. In Rails 4, at least, the `CollectionProxy` contains a cache on a collection of objects that are associated via `:has_many`. [This example](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/reload) from the documentation outlines that caching / reloading process.

I did a quick search for "cache" on the `CollectionProxy` source for both [Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb) and [Rails 3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb), and it isn't mentioned in the Rails 3.2 documentation. But it could have been implemented before the documentation was changed.

Also, maybe this is ideological, but using `#is_a?` could be avoided. You could just use `:respond_to?(:each)`, so that you can use any sort of `Enumerable` in there.

EDIT! Check it out, from the [CollectionProxy source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb):

```
# This class has most of the basic instance methods removed, and delegates
# unknown methods to <tt>@target</tt> via <tt>method_missing</tt>. As a
# corner case, it even removes the +class+ method and that's why you get
#
#   blog.posts.class # => Array
#
# though the object behind <tt>blog.posts</tt> is not an Array, but an
# ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation.
#
# The <tt>@target</tt> object is not \loaded until needed. For example,
#
#   blog.posts.count
```

It looks like `comment.replies` is actually just giving you a `HasManyAssociation`, rather than an actual object. Since `CollectionProxy` is new in Rails 3.1, that's probably your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it soon (right now I put that on hold and taking care of other stuff) and I will come back to you with the result